System Freezes; Likely Graphics Drivers Related
   Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 Ti
   32GB RAM
   Intel(R) Core i7-9700F CPU $ 3.00GHz
   OS: Xubuntu
I don't know how useful the particular log I provide here is. It's the output from journalctl -b-1 after encountering this problem (again). It's been an ongoing issue for several days now, where I will be live streaming using OBS and regardless of which option I set for encoding, after some amount of time the entire system will freeze and I have to reboot to use it more. I spent a lot of time looking for solutions, which mostly tried to fix this by messing with the Nvidia drivers, most recently I just downgraded from version 550 to version 470, which is why I'm uncertain about the usefulness of the logs, because for all I know switching drivers and procrastinating the customary reboot afterwards caused an identical but unrelated problem. I'm uncertain what version at present is best for this. I'm also not certain that it's caused by Nvidia, but it's the only cause that I can think of.
I previously had the same issue on Debian, and I had assumed that it was my own fault for one reason or another, but after encountering it having switched to Xubuntu I didn't think it was something I could have done.
The log: https://pastebin.com/rTPJYZbD
Edit/Update: Switching back to 550 until given other directions

Using this guide:
https://github.com/oddmario/NVIDIA-Ubuntu-Driver-Guide?tab=readme-ov-file#-installing-through-the-graphics-drivers-ppa-repository-recommended
I'm installing version 560, will need a bit of time to test it, still open to talking and hearing possible solutions in case this doesn't help.
